# IOS MFMailComposeViewController link a href did not click

Tags: ios, href, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a problem.

My link is HTML, I can see 'blue' but if I click it, doesn't open safari mobile. Is allowed to me edit the text.

In a class I have this:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            self.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [self setSubject: @"Subject"];
            [self setMessageBody: @"<h2>Body</h2><a href='http://www.google.com'>link example</a>" isHTML: YES];
        }
```

[image]

Comment: The link doesn't work in the mail composer. The link works when the user views the received email.

Comment: @rmaddy 10x you man:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href=\"http://www.google.com">link example</a>
```

**Edited:**

Try this working code:

```
messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href:\"\nhttps://www.google.com\">\nhttps://www.google.com</a>"];
```

Comment: You would need to escape both double quotes inside the `NSString`. But there is nothing wrong with using single quotes. That isn't the problem.

Comment: @HoussamHammoud see edited answer, One more thing it will not work while you open Mail composer, It will work when this mail will open up form sent mail box

Comment: ok 10x man when i receive the email the a href work perfectly :)

Comment: @HoussamHammoud All the best :)

Comment: @rmaddy yes i already pointed him regarding this in my earlier comment, you can check.

Comment: Yes @rmaddy I thanked you in your comment also please check :)